# немогу отразить картину в сайте

Tags: html, spring-boot

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head xmlns:th="http://www.thmyleaf.org">


    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="asserts/style.css"/>

</head>
<body>

   <h1>My first site</h1>
   <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
   <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</p>
   <p>when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </p>
   <img th:src=@{assets/'+${projects.projectName}'+.gif")/>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: что простите хотите сделать?

Comment: @stack-it, вопрошающий забыл поместить HTML в код с блоком. Исправил. Дальше я пас, так как в Spring Framework не разбираюсь и потому про конструкцию `th:src=@{assets/'+${projects.projectName}'+.gif")` ничего не знаю.